# Converting string to ToolStripMenuItem

Tags: c#

I have a menu structure already set up on a form and I want to programatically enable or disable certain menu items using a database.

I have got to the last stage where I have a class of `AllowedMenu` and `CodeNames` (which match the toolstripmenuitems exactly), and all I want to do it convert the `CodeName` into a `ToolStripMenuItem` from a String.

How could I do this?

Comment: Is AllowedMenu a boolean and CodeNames are string properties in your particular class? be some more specific about the object you use

Comment: Basically yes, that is correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem to have found something that works...

```
var m = menuStrip1.Items.Find(menuItem.CodeName, true);
var o = m.ToList();
foreach (var p in o)
{
    p.Visible = false;
}
```

Thanks all..

Answer (score 1):

You can access ToolStripItems throught `Items` property of the `ToolStrip`. If you have exactly name of the item (in `CodeName` variable), you could do something like this:

```
if (toolStrip1.Items.ContainsKey(CodeName)) //Just in case... 
{
    var yourItem = toolStrip1.Items[CodeName];
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly if it's directly on the menu bar, but what about if I need to disable an item in the drop down, i.e. You have File > Exit, but you want to disable the exit button?